# Using existing aws amplify project in react js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

I use AWS amplify with auth, dynamodb and graphql API for react native app. Now I need to add the existing backend to web react js app. I run the command below and get amplify backend folder with API, auth, and functions. There is a missing graphql folder (GraphQL client ) for queries and mutations. How to get GraphQL client folder for fetching data from db?

```
amplify pull --appId someidgoeshere --envName dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying folder (src/graphql->mutation.js,queries.js,subscription.js) from an existing project works well. If there is a better solution I would love to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `amplify api gql-compile` to re-compile your `src/graphql/*` queries and mutations.

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/overview#update-schema